# How to get the string between matching parentheses in Elixir in functional way?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to get the content between a matching pair of parentheses that could have 0 or more pairs of nested parentheses. This is a well-known problem. For example, when I give `"Well (this part (should be) (in the (result)), but) not this part"` as the input, `"this part (should be) (in the (result)), but"` should be the result.

The following Elixir code does the job. It traverses the string, counts matching pair of parentheses, then return the correct substring.

The thing is, it is identical to the code I would write in an imperative language. I'm wondering if there could be a different way to write this code in a different, more idiomatic functional way. Can someone help me get better at functional programming?

```
def get_content_of_first_pair_of_parentheses(s) do
  cl = String.to_charlist(s)
  first_opening = Enum.find_index(cl, fn(x) -> x == 40 end)
  sub_cl = Enum.slice(cl, (first_opening+1)..-1)
  content = Enum.reduce_while(sub_cl,
                              {[], 1},
                              fn(x, {list, counter} = acc) ->
                                if counter < 1 do
                                  {:halt, acc}
                                else 
                                  case x do
                                    40 -> {:cont, {[x | list], counter + 1}}
                                    41 -> {:cont, {[x | list], counter - 1}}
                                    _ -> {:cont, {[x | list], counter}}
                                  end
                                end
                              end)

  content
  |> elem(0)
  |> Enum.slice(1..-1)
  |> Enum.reverse()
  |> List.to_string()
end
```

Edit: Here's the code that I ended up with. It's the same one as @dogbert  suggested, but reorganized in a way that I find more readable.

```
def get_content_of_first_pair_of_parentheses(s) do
  subs = substring_after_first_opening_paren(s)

  length_after_first_opening_paren = byte_size(subs)

  length_after_matching_closing_paren =
    subs
    |> substring_after_matching_closing_paren(0)
    |> byte_size()

  binary_part(subs, 0, length_after_first_opening_paren - length_after_matching_closing_paren)
end

defp substring_after_first_opening_paren(<<"(", rest::binary>>), do: rest
defp substring_after_first_opening_paren(<<_, rest::binary>>), do: substring_after_first_opening_paren(rest)

defp substring_after_matching_closing_paren(<<")", _::binary>> = rest, 0), do: rest
defp substring_after_matching_closing_paren(<<")", rest::binary>>, n), do: substring_after_matching_closing_paren(rest, n - 1)
defp substring_after_matching_closing_paren(<<"(", rest::binary>>, n), do: substring_after_matching_closing_paren(rest, n + 1)
defp substring_after_matching_closing_paren(<<_::utf8, rest::binary>>, n), do: substring_after_matching_closing_paren(rest, n)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd do this with pattern matching on binaries. Creating a charlist is fairly inefficient in most cases. The following code does not create any new binary; it just creates sub-binaries of the existing one and returns a sub-binary at the end.

```
defmodule A do
  def go(<<"(", rest::binary>>) do
    remaining = byte_size(go(rest, 0))
    binary_part(rest, 0, byte_size(rest) - remaining)
  end

  def go(<<_::utf8, rest::binary>>), do: go(rest)

  def go(<<")", _::binary>> = rest, 0), do: rest
  def go(<<")", rest::binary>>, n), do: go(rest, n - 1)
  def go(<<"(", rest::binary>>, n), do: go(rest, n + 1)
  def go(<<_::utf8, rest::binary>>, n), do: go(rest, n)
end

IO.puts A.go("Well (this part (should be) (in the (result)), but) not this part")
IO.puts A.go("(foo bar ())")
IO.puts A.go("(foo bar ()) baz")
IO.puts A.go("zz (foo bar ()) baz")
IO.puts A.go("foo (bar) baz)")
```

Output:

```
this part (should be) (in the (result)), but
foo bar ()
foo bar ()
foo bar ()
bar
```

The logic is fairly similar to yours. First, skip while you find an opening parenthesis. Then, keep track of the nesting level of parentheses, and as soon as you find a closing parenthesis and the level is 0, terminate.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regex to simply get the output you want:

```
str = "Well (this part (should be) (in the (result)), but) not this part"
Regex.run(~r/\((.*)\)/, str) |> Enum.at(1)
```

Since by default the regex patters match greedily, it'll match everything from the first paran to the last

Comment: This produces an unexpected result on unmatched parentheses ("`(opening1 (opening2 closing1) rest"`.)

Comment: If there's unmatched parentheses, I cannot automatically check if the string has semantically valid meaning so I'd just dismiss it as invalid input. So it's not an issue for me.

On the other hand Regex has problem dealing with multiple top level parentheses. For example, `I want the content (In this parenthesis (plus other stuff)) but not the one in (this parenthesis)` won't give the result I want.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is similar to Dogbert’s one, but it is pure streaming:

```
defmodule A do
  def go(input), do: go(input, 0, "")
  def go(<<"(", rest::binary>>, 0, _), do: go(rest, 1, "")
  def go(<<"(", rest::binary>>, num, acc), do: go(rest, num + 1, acc <> "(")
  def go(<<")", _::binary>>, 1, acc), do: acc
  def go(<<")", rest::binary>>, num, acc), do: go(rest, num - 1, acc <> ")")
  def go(<<_::binary-size(1), rest::binary>>, 0, _), do: go(rest, 0, "")
  def go(<<letter::binary-size(1), rest::binary>>, num, acc),
    do: go(rest, num, acc <> letter)
  def go(_, _, acc),
    do: "⚑ Unmatched parentheses found. Accumulated so far: “#{acc}”"
end

IO.puts A.go("Well (this part (should be) (in the (result)), but) not this part")
IO.puts A.go("(foo bar ()")
```

Produces:

```
this part (should be) (in the (result)), but
⚑ Unmatched parentheses found. Accumulated so far: “foo bar ()”
```